# Is there CSS Meta Framework for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css

Is there CSS Meta Framefork for ASP.NET?
Something like LESS or xCSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the very interesting framework called [DotLess](http://www.dotlesscss.org/).

dotLess is actually a port of .LESS for ASP.Net. The framework is implemented in form of a ASP.Net Handler and works for files with .LESS extensions just like LESS.

I've attempted implementing it in one of my projects but for some reason while it worked on my dev machine I couldn't get it to work on the server. That was more than 6 months ago though and implementing it is still in my agenda. When I am a little less busy.

I would definitely recommend it.

Comment: +1 it very useful.  does it work well? has it bugs, features?

Comment: It worked well on my dev machine. But like I said I couldn't get it to work on the server due to some configuration issues. Probably my mistake. There was not a lot of documentation available when I checked last. But the guys who made it have a google-group and entertain questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at [Chripy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/), it can handle LESS and Coffeescript compilation + css/js merging, minification and validation, a great tool!